# Illustrator: How to split text in half?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm trying to create a strikethrough text similar to the "bullet through text" effect in illustrator.
[image: what i want]
I have a piece of text which I converted to outlines, then placed a long rectangle on top of it. I've tried Minus Front, Divide, Clipping Mask and many other things but it doesn't work. The whole shape disappears or I'm left with areas that are common to text and the rectangle which is the opposite of what I want.
[image: what i have]
Can you suggest how to achieve this? I believe the problem is because the different shapes don't overlap each other and are a group of separate shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods to achieve this.
Here's the one I would use, because it gives great control over the position of the substracted part while in Isolation mode.
I would use the **Substract** method in pathfinder, **holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd>** key while clicking on it.
See example below (I applied a shape to the red form, then expanded it in order to outline strokes):

[image: substract]

Comment: Excellent. I was almost right. Just an Alt key was required ;)